# Heroku supported SBT version

Tags: heroku, sbt

Heroku documentation states [SBT v0.12.3 is supported](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scala-support#build-behavior). I set my `project/build.properties` to `sbt.version=0.12.3` and push, but Heroku responds with "Error, SBT version 0.12.3 not supported".

Which versions are supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error, it seems that v0.12.2 is the highest supported version at this time, despite what the documentation says.